# How to send variables with drupal_goto with drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to use drupal_goto function but it is redirect to wrong URL

here is my code

```
$dis='user/' . $account->uid . '/edit/?id=6356928';
 drupal_goto($dis);
```

the problem with the ID

any suggestions ??

Answer (score 5):

[drupal_goto](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal%5fgoto/7) uses the same `$options` settings as [url()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/url/7).

Try to do the following

```
drupal_goto("user/" . $account->uid . "/edit", array(
    'query' => array(
        'id' => '6356928',
    ),
));
```